# Facebook Login - Tell joomla to login

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, joomla

I'm developing a facebook login *(FB SDK Javascript)* for joomla site to add alternative way to register/login.

What I've done are:

- Create FB app
- Insert relevant code to my site
- Get connected stat from `FB.login()`.
- Got basic information: name, email...etc

I got found below function that use to login in joomla, but this way require me to provide username & password.

```
$result = JFactory::getApplication()->login(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password), array('remember' => true));
```

My question is:

After I got the permission from FB, I wish to login to Joomla without enter email and password, so which module/helper/function should I use?

Comment: what not an extension like http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/22865 there is also more paid and free extension for facebook login

Comment: i've bought extension "Instant facebook login", but this module got some issue/restriction and their support seems not willing to fix for me so ended up develop this function by myself.

Comment: contact to their support to fix else you need more effort to make fb login for joomla have good knowledge of joomla code and login process

Comment: i've already contact their support, but they seems not willing to do

Comment: ok take a refund and go for another extension  check for good rating and reviews extension

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)